# Detect when a UITextView has been edited

Tags: swift, uitextview

## Text Editor

### What I'm Doing

#### Text View

I am attempting to create a UITextView that is a code editor on IOS and I am trying to make different types of code be different colors so everything isn't just one color (such as comments would be grey).

#### Problem

The problem I am having is that I am linking the Text View like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
```

and I need to detect when the textView has been changed do you know of any way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do this, you need to conform to the `UITextViewDelegate` protocol and then set the textView's delegate to self.

So, after `UIViewController` on the beginning of this view controller, you need to add the protocol conformance. Example

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
```

then set the delegate in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textView.delegate = self
}
```

Now, you're set up for success. All of the delegate methods on UITextViewDelegate are optional, so you only need to implement the ones you want. In this case, the one you want to implement is `func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView)`

That method will get triggered every single time the text in the text field updates.

Answer (score 5):

Create `Editing Changed` `@IBAction` from your `UITextView` in storyBoard into your viewController.

[image]

Comment: Ooh, doing it with an IBAction. That's an interesting way of doing it. Cool idea.

Comment: your welcome, and please vote up if you like or accept.

Comment: Well, I have a competing answer... but ok. :)